# Splitting a string with advanced regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string of the following form using a regex:

`"/say hello world (hello there) (how (are you))"`

This should split into:

- /say
- hello
- world
- (hello there)
- (how (are you))

Splitting on `" "`(space) obviously doesn't work, as I don't want to split strings inside brackets. How can something like this be achieved?
Also, worth noting: I'm using PCRE for parsing.

Comment: You may need to write a rudimentary parser to handle your use case, as a simple regex can't handle it.

Comment: Okay, this is what I had before. I was just wondering if there was a clean, better way to do it with regex.

Comment: fun fact: regexp as a formal language are actually not able to solve your problem. On the other hand most implementations of regexpes actually are able to solve your problem. So if you want a solution, you'd have to tell us which parser exactly you are using.

Comment: I'm using PCRE, I assume this is what you mean. I'm adding it to the post.

Comment: Regex can certainly be something you use in your parser, but by itself it can't handle it (note: there _is_ such a thing as recursive regex, e.g. in Perl, but Java does not support this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can create your own parser for this:**
 1. Iterate over string characters to find `" "`, if you find `(` increase one counter (create in your method) and when you find  `)` decrease it.
 2. If you find `" "` and your counter is 0 then take substring till that point and add in an array, (reset internal variables to if any to work in loop).
 3. if you find `" "` and counter is still not zero then ignore and go to step 1 again.